# How to find MariaDb/Mysql structure differences

Tags: mysql, mariadb, alter-table, merge

I have two similar databases with many tables, in one of these there was some alter commands maybe changing data types or adding some columns.

Exists a free analyzer/merging tool to check their differences? Please consider that I need only structure difference, not data differences.

Comment: How about using [mysqldbcompare](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-utilities/1.6/en/mysqldbcompare.html) and specifying applicable options such as `--skip-row-count --skip-data-check`, etc.? I don't have time to test and confirm but wanted to try to give you a potential starting point at least. If you're on Windows then you can download this utility from https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/file/?id=468268 so it may be worth a look at least for you.

Comment: The Percona Toolkit has a couple of tools in this area.

Comment: Try MySQL Workbench, see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-design-schema.html